# Работа с mysql с PDO

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Обучаясь работать с `PDO mysql` возникла одна проблема: 
При работе этого кода все работает прекрасно и данные вставляются в базу:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=zv', 'root', '');
$activation = 0;
    $hash = md5($user_mail.'12589');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO regs (username, lastname, reg_email, activation, hash) VALUES (:username, :lastname, :reg_email, :activation, :hash)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', '1');
    $stmt->bindValue(':lastname', '1');
    $stmt->bindValue(':reg_email', '1');
    $stmt->bindValue(':activation', 1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':hash', '1');
    $stmt->execute();
```

При работе вот этого кода данные не вставляются в базу:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=zv', 'root', '');
    $activation = 0;
        $hash = md5($user_mail.'12589');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO regs (username, lastname, reg_email, activation, hash) VALUES (:username, :lastname, :reg_email, :activation, :hash)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $user_name);
        $stmt->bindValue(':lastname', $user_last_name);
        $stmt->bindValue(':reg_email', $user_mail);
        $stmt->bindValue(':activation', $activation);
        $stmt->bindValue(':hash', $hash);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Переменные в `bindValue` заранее определены.

Comment: Очевидно, переменные $user_name / $user_last_name / $user_mail / $activation / $hash хранят некорректные значения. Вы пробовали узнать что в них содержится перед началом выполнения запроса?

Comment: @uzumaxy да, в них хранятся данные строкового типа, и передаются в скрипт по GET, буквально так : $user_name = "abcdef"; и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так? (явно задать тип данных)

```
...
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lastname', $user_last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':reg_email', $user_mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':activation', $activation, PDO::PARAM_STR); //или PDO::PARAM_INT
    $stmt->bindValue(':hash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы подставить значение из переменной нужно использовать метод bindParam(), а не bindValue() и явно указывать тип.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```